# Is there any way to get notifications in visual studio about new commits in my azure repos by other members?

Tags: azure-repos

Microsoft states, 'Notifications help you and your team stay informed about activity that occurs within your Azure DevOps projects. You're notified when changes occur to work items, code reviews, pull requests, source control files, and builds. You can be notified via email. For example, you can get notified whenever you resolve a bug or are assigned a work item.'

Though this is helpful, this is all about email notifications. Is there any way to get notified through desktop notifications or in the Visual Studio itself, when I have logged in to my VS with the same account. Even a small suggestion would be very helpful to me.